# strange folder being created when i compile my coffeescript project

Tags: bash, coffeescript

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
coffee --output ./js  --compile ./
coffee --output ./js/public/ --compile ./public/
```

When I run this bash script there is a folder called "blic" that is created in the `js/` directory. I assume its half of "public". Why is it being created?

Answer (score 1):

Given a directory structure like this:

```
a.coffee
abcdefgh/
    c.coffee
public/
    b.coffee
```

If I say `coffee --output ./js --compile ./`, I get this structure:

```
js/
    a.js
    blic/
        b.js
    cdefgh/
        c.js
```

And if I say `coffee --output ./jsx --compile ./`, I get this structure:

```
jsx/
    a.js
    blic/
        b.js
    cdefgh/
        c.js
```

And it is still only stripping off the first two characters. That would suggest that the `./` source directory (which has length two) is confusing `coffee` rather than the `./js` or `./jsx` argument to `--output`.

However, if I say `coffee --output ./js --compile .`, then I get this:

```
js/
    a.js
    public/
        b.js
    abcdefgh/
        c.js
```

Apparently, `coffee` correctly interprets `.` as the current directory but sees `./` as a two character prefix of some sort. That gives you one work around for this odd problem.

If I move the CoffeeScript files to their own directory:

```
cs/
    a.coffee
    abcdefgh/
        c.coffee
    public/
        b.coffee
```

and say `coffee --output js --compile cs` from the directory containing `cs/`, I get the same output as from `coffee --output ./js --compile .` (i.e. a sensible structure in `cs/`).

We see three things here:

1. `coffee --output js --compile .` works so you can do that instead of using `./`.
2. Everything works if you keep your CS and JS files in different directories.
3. You don't need to compile subdirectories separately from their parent directories, `coffee` walks the directory tree all by itself. The [docs](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) aren't exactly clear on this behavior but the examples suggest it.

I'd call this a bug in `coffee` but at least you have some workarounds.